# In WPF, accessing containers within ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, itemssource

I'm creating a `DerivedListBox : ListBox` and a `DerivedHeaderedContentControl : HeaderedContentControl`, which will serve as a container for each item in the `ListBox`.

In order to calculate the size available for the expanded content of the `DerivedHeaderedContentControl`s, I am storing each container object in a list within the `DerivedListBox`.  This way I can calculate the height of the headers of each `DerivedHeaderedContentControl` and subtract that from the total size available to the `DerivedListBox`.  This would be the size available for the expanded content of a `DerivedHeaderedContentControl`.

```
public class DerivedHeaderedContentControl : HeaderedContentControl
{
    // Do some binding to DerivedListBox to calculate height.
}

public class DerivedListBox : ListBox
{
    private List<DerivedHeaderedContentControl> containers;

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        DerivedHeaderedContentControl val = new DerivedHeaderedContentControl();
        this.containers.Add(val);
        return val;
    }

    // Do some binding to calculate height available for an expanded
    // container by iterating over containers.
}
```

The problem comes in when the `DerivedListBox`'s `ItemsSource` is cleared (or an item in the items source is removed).  How can I determine when the `ItemsSource` is cleared so that I can clear the containers list?

Comment: Is any way to access the internal containers created via GetContainerForItemOverride() from within the DerivedListBox class?  I would assume they are managed within the class, and having access to those objects, rather than managing my own list, would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular scenario, you should probably use [`ItemsContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.itemschanged.aspx) event.